# Unable to launch Spark

Tags: 14.04, java, environment-variables, openjdk, jdk

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483409/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-04). I am getting this error:

> spark-class: line 86: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java: No such file or directory

And to my surprise, I have:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64
gsamaras@gsamaras:/usr/lib/jvm$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: No such file or directory
```

How to correct it?

More information (from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/703989)):

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ls -alh /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 10 00:54 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ls -alh /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb 10 00:54 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

In the `~/.profile` I had appended:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

from my [Hadoop experience](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/hadoop-cluster-with-pc-and-virtualbox/). When I sourced that I was able to launch Spark.

---

EDIT:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/conf$ ls
docker.properties.template  metrics.properties.template   spark-env.sh.template
fairscheduler.xml.template  slaves.template
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure whether Spark will work with Java 7, but if not the obvious solution is to install Java 8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answering "yes" in the correct spots should get you Java 8 as default, otherwise

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

will do the trick.

**Update**: 
Having said that, if you want to run with OpenJDK 7, you've got to find out where `JAVA_HOME` is set wrongly as per

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:/usr/lib/jvm$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle: No such file or directory
```

Since you try to correct that in `.profile` (you did `hash -r` or re-login?) you might want to check `load-spark-env.sh` or other scripts that are executed prior to launching Spark proper.

Cheers,

Comment: It seems it does working with Java 7, so I'd rather *not*installing Java 8, since it's not in the repositories.

Comment: I interpret your edit as you're now able to run Spark? If so, the problem is really where `JAVA_HOME` is set wrongly on your box. See my update and go looking :-) `grep` is your friend.

Comment: I did that (looking in the Spark directory, in `conf/` for such a script but nothing. I am updating with the scripts I see. I am not sure how to use `grep` here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318343/create-jar-for-spark/

Answer (score 0):

just try to locate the spark-env.sh file in your folder and the check the JAVA_HOME given in it. The location given in the etc/environment must be same in both the files